# Is composing homotopies of spheres bilinear?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

$\newcommand{\SS}{\mathbb{S}}$ For nonnegative integers $n, m$ and $k$ consider the map
$$
c: \pi_n(\SS^m) \times \pi_m(\SS^k) \to \pi_n(\SS^k)
$$
given by composition, i.e. $([f], [g]) \mapsto [g \circ f] = g_*[f]$. $g_*$ is a homomorphism $\pi_n(\SS^m) \to \pi_n(\SS^k)$, so $c$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-linear (additive) in $[f]$. Is this also additive in in $[g]$?

Comment: I think you're stating that $h_*(f+g)=h_*f+h_*g$ (which is true), and asking if $(f+g)_*h$ is the same as $f_*h+g_*h$? This is only true in general if $h$ is a co-H-map, and so in particular if $h$ is a suspension. (think about how the addition is defined).

Comment: Relatedly, you can ask if precomposition by a degree n map is the same as post composition by a degree n map. This is only true after a suspension. One counter example is given by the hopf map $S^3 \rightarrow S^2$. Postcomposition by -1 does not affect the homotopy type of this map. As a result of this and the previous statement, we deduce that the suspension of the hopf map has order 2.

Comment: This is a special case of @Tyrone's comment since we take the sum to be $1+1+ \dots +1$, n times. (And just use basic group theory to deduce it for negatives).